# AngularJS Invoke method in another controller

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

To simplify it.
I have 3 tabs with lists of items. (Country, City, Stree). In my app those are diferent things but this is to simplyfy it.

In those 3 tabs I'm listing all the countes, cities and streets. I have seperate controller for each tab. CountryController, CityController and StreetController.

**What I want to achieve.**
When users clicks on country in first tab I wast to invoke function in CitiesControlelr that will return all the cities in given country. When your clicks on City I want to invoke function in StreetController that will return all the streets in that city.

How to achieve this "communication" between controllers? What is proper way of making it?

Answer (score 0):

You could put an object in a scope that is parent to all of your controllers' scopes to store the selected values.

```
<div ng-init="current = {}">
    <div ng-controller="CountryController as countryCtrl">
        <select ng-options="country.code as country.label for country in countryCtrl.countries" 
                ng-model="current.country">
        </select>
    </div>
    <div ng-controller="CityController as cityCtrl">
        <select ng-options="city.code as city.label for city in cityCtrl.countriesFor(current.country)"
                ng-model="current.city">
        </selected>
    </div>

</div>
```